# React Native TypeScript Property 'xxx' does not exist on type 'xx'

Tags: typescript, react-native, styled-components

Hello I Converted React Native Java Script Project into Typescript all working is fine but some warning is showing me please any one help me out in this ! How to pass props from other folder please look into

```ts
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { Text, Container, Canvas, Button } from "../../components";
import styled from "styled-components/native";

const Input = styled.TextInput`
  width: 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-top: ${(props) => props.theme.spacing.sm};
  padding-bottom: ${(props) => props.theme.spacing.sm};
  border-bottom-color: ${(props) => props.theme.color.white};
`;
```

Errors are

- Error Property 'spacing' does not exist on type 'DefaultTheme'.
- Error Property 'color' does not exist on type 'DefaultTheme'.

theme.tsx

```tsx
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";
import { ThemeProvider as StyledThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import themes from "../themes/";

type ThemeContextType = {
  theme: string;
  setTheme: (value: string) => void;
};
const ThemeContext = createContext<ThemeContextType | undefined>(undefined);
export const ThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(themes["dark"]);
  const [themeKey, setThemeKey] = useState("dark");

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, themeKey }}>
      <StyledThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</StyledThemeProvider>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useTheme = () => {
  return useContext(ThemeContext);
};
```

themes/index.ts

```ts
import dark from "./dark";
import light from "./light";

const themes = {
  dark,
  light,
};
export default themes;
```

light.tsx

```ts
const light = {
  color: {
    background: "#ffffff",
    black: "#ffffff",
    white: "#000000",
  },
  spacing: {
    xs: "6px",
    sm: "8px",
  },
};

export default light;
```

Comment: You're using `theme.spacing.sm` but your `theme` consists of `dark` and `light`. If you look at `lights.tsx` spacing is inside of the `light` object. So for the sake of assuming light theme it would have to be `props.theme.light.spacing.sm` and for the other error it would have to be `props.theme.light.color.white`.

Comment: @DrZoo the styled components inherit the `theme` from the `ThemeProvider`. OP is using it correctly

Comment: But in d same Java script code working Fine...! we getting warning in only TypeScript ! as u mentioned i tried props.theme.light.spacing.sm but the same error comes again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Styled Components documentation - [Create a declarations file](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#create-a-declarations-file)

You need to define the shape of your theme objects for Typescript

```ts
// styled.d.ts
declare module 'styled-components/native' {
  export interface DefaultTheme {
    color: {
      background: string;
      black: string;
      white: string;
    };
    spacing: {
      xs: string;
      sm: string;
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure you read the [Typescript](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#typescript) section of the documentation thoroughly.